# "ERROR: type "pg_catalog.varchar_latin" does not exist"

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am getting the below error while trying to create a table. Does anyone know how can I fix this?

> ERROR:  type "pg_catalog.varchar_latin" does not exist

I am trying to create a table and set its character set to Latin:

```
CREATE TABLE test (name VARCHAR(250) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT NULL, [...]
```

Is there a way to set character to Latin in PostgreSQL without setting the whole server encoding?

Comment: What are you running to get that error? What version of postgres? What have you already tried to fix this?

Comment: That's not a PostgreSQL standard type. You'll have to tell us more about what you are doing (SQL statements), How your DB is set up etc.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the `create table` statement you are using. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Redshift tables are UTF8. Redshift does not support other character sets.